$A^2 + I = 0$ show that the degree of $A$ is even
I'm a first year computer science student and I have a question which goes like this:
let A be a $n \times n$ matrix $(n \in \mathbb{N})$
such that $A^2 + I = 0$.
Prove that $n$ is even.
Now, I came to a conclusion that a matrix of this form can work:
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &-1 \\
0 & 0 &\cdots & 1 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
(the degree of this matrix is even obviously)
and of course I also tried a version with an odd degree which produced $I$ instead of $-I$.
The question is how do I prove that?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Can you use properties of determinants?

You probably mean $A$ is a real matrix? If $A$ is allowed to have complex entries, this is definitely not true. For example, if you take $A=i I$, then $A^2+I=0$ regardless of $n$.

Why is the degree “even obviously”?

Suppose $A^2+I_n=0$. Then $A^2=-I_n$. If $n$ is odd then $det(-I_{n})=-1$ so $-1=det(A^2)=det(A)^2$ but $det(A)\in\mathbb{R}$ so $det(A)^2\ge 0$. This is a contradiction. ($I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix)

Or: $A^2=-I_n$ implies $0 \le (\det(A))^2 = \det(A^2) = \det(-I_n) = (-1)^n$ and so $n$ is even.

No no! You have to show it in such a way that it can be called proof and answer for any situation. I mean that the solution you have to provide for these questions should always answer. For example, have it here:
Let $I$ be the identity and $O$ be the zero matrix belongs to $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ (the set of all the $n\times n$ matrices with real entries) and $$A^2 + I = O$$ so, $$A^2=-I$$ and because $det()$ is a function we have $$det(A^2)=det(-I)$$
so let's break the problem and find them!
we know that
$$det(-I) = \begin{cases}\text{1,} &\quad\text{n is even}\\\text{-1,} &\quad\text{n is odd} \\\end{cases}$$
on the other hand we know that $$det(A^2)=(det(A))^2$$
and by simplifying we have
$$(det(A))^2 = \begin{cases}\text{1,} &\quad\text{n is even}\\\text{-1,} &\quad\text{n is odd} \\\end{cases}$$
and in other way
$$det(A) = \begin{cases}\ \pm1 &\quad\text{n is even}\\ \pm i &\quad\text{n is odd} \\\end{cases}$$
but here in this case $det()$ is a real function and so at least $n$ must be even so that $det(A)$ be real.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Format suggestion:  \det.  Did you mean $\det(-I)$ where you typed $\det(I)$?

@J.W.Tanner yes thank you
