If the square of a matrix is negative definite, then the dimension is even.
I am trying to solve the following problem. I'm studying for an exam.
Let $A$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix such that $A^2$ is negative definite. Prove that $n$ must be even.
The only hint given is that $A^2$ being negative definite means that $\langle A^2x, x \rangle < 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}$. It does not say, but I suppose $A$ must also be symmetric. My attempt at a solution is the following. Let $x$ be an arbitrary eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ (negative definite real matrices are diagonalizable). We have that
\begin{equation}
\langle A^2x, x \rangle = (AAx)^{\top}x = x^{\top}A^2x = \lambda^2 x^{\top}x = \lambda^2 ||x||^2 < 0.
\end{equation}
This means that $\lambda^2 < 0$ and thus, every eigenvalue of $A$ must be complex. Hence, $n$ must be even. But we also have
\begin{equation}
||Ax||^2 = \langle Ax, Ax \rangle = (Ax)^{\top}Ax = x^{\top}A^2x = \langle A^2x, x \rangle < 0,
\end{equation}
which makes no sense. Where have I gone wrong? Could it be that in this case negative definite does not entail symmetric? Any help is appreciated.

If the eigenvalues of A are complex then A cannot be symmetric.

essentially a duplicate of this from yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4921001/a2-i-0-show-that-the-degree-of-a-is-even , check $\det\big(A^2\big)=\det\big(A\big)^2$

@user8675309 It's vaguely similar.

If $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, then as you showed it is impossible for $A^2$ to be negative definite.  However, it is possible to have $A^2$ negative definite if $A$ is not symmetric.  For example, $$A = \pmatrix{0 & 1\cr -1 & 0\cr}$$ will do it, where $A^2 = -I$.
One way to see the result is that any real $n \times n$ matrix with odd $n$ must have a real eigenvalue (because the non-real ones come in complex-conjugate pairs) and corresponding real eigenvector.  If $\lambda$ and $v$ are such an eigenvalue and eigenvector, then $\langle A^2 v, v \rangle = \lambda^2 \|v\|^2 \ge 0$.

It seems so simple now that you've solved it. Thank you very much.
